# In IE6, when I display a modal, a dropdownlist from the parent page is visible on top of the model

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, popup, modal-dialog

In IE6, when I display a modal, a dropdownlist from the parent page is visible on top of the model.

i.e. the dropdownlist from the parent page is overlaying above the model popup.

In firefox and IE 7 it is fine (the dropdownlist is tucked underneath the model like it is suppose to).

Any ideas what it can be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE 6 has an issue with this.  The fix is to throw an iframe behind your modal to block the stuff behind from showing.

There is a jQuery plugin designed to address this particular issue.  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe

Comment: can't seem to get it to work.
I am calling $(mydropdownID).bgiframe(); but it is still visible.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to hide all the dropdowns when you call the modal and show them again when you close it.